# <git push> from local repo --> online SSL Cert prob. verify CA cert is ok

Tags: git, bash, github-for-mac

i'm trying to setup github locally, on an old mac at a location i spend sig. periods of time, to facilitate work/study thru gitHub.  I'm using Terminal, generating my first local repo, to push to online repo  / .

By following v.comprehensive tutorials (by Lauren Orsini, of readwrite.com) progress was good until i was blocked by an error message, regarding unverifiable CA cert. blocking SSL, below:

```
cmd:-
< apple-macbooks-pro-69:introGit applemacbook$ git push >
er:-
<  error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/gpud/introGit.git/info/refs >
```

On reading help docs etc. the only solution/advice found, was upgrading my OS (current osX: 10.5.8) impossible due to age /ltd. HD space of the macbook (09). I also noticed a warning notice regarding my Firefox version on gitHub prompting an update (but again, it's the latest poss vers. for the macbook os).

Is there any other means of providing a CA verification,on OSX 10.5.8
- anything in $ git config ?

- any means of forcing a push?
- any thing i can do in my mac settings?

to rectify this security related block

I've looked hard for an answer, and am seeking advice from this prestigious pool of expertise/knowledge as the related project is for my dissertation (v. imp)
thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Try `git config --global http.sslverify false`, then push again.